# Execution of a Java program by a trigger.

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to make an update trigger execute a Java program.

I have a table `T1` with a column named `Flag`.  Whenever `Flag` changes, I want to run a trigger that results in an execution of a Java program.

Is this possible?

Comment: What if the transaction rollback later, will the execution be undone? Call back the missile? You do not solve this through triggers, you use queues and fire the program *after* commit.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit , what im doing is i have only two values in Flag i.e True and False , every time value toggles , java program should run

Comment: What database are we talking about?  Is the Java program running inside the database (i.e. a Java stored procedure in Oracle)?  Or are you trying to execute an external application?  Does that application reside on the database server or on a different machine?

Comment: Database - MySql
Java program is external
programm resides on a same machine

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using the [MySQL User-Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html) (see [MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10)) and installing the [lib_mysqludf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme)

Then, for example, you can write your own trigger calling the sys_exec like this:

```
delimiter |
 CREATE TRIGGER testtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON T1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE result int(10);
   IF NEW.Flag <> OLD.Flag THEN  
     SET result = sys_exec('/path/to/javabin -jar your.jar');
     -- other kind of works and checks...
   END IF;
 END;
|
```

The `result` contains the exit code of the external program

There are other useful functions in this library:

- **sys_eval** : executes an arbitrary command, and returns it's output.
- **sys_get** : gets the value of an environment variable
- **sys_set** : create an environment variable, or update the value of an existing environment variable
- **sys_exec** : executes an arbitrary command, and returns it's exit code

More info [here](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/blob/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.html)

Try it on a dev env and...

> **Be very careful in deciding whether you need this function**. UDFs are
>   available to all database users - you cannot grant EXECUTE privileges
>   for them. As the commandstring passed to `sys_exec` can do
>   pretty much everything, **exposing the function poses a very real**
>    **security hazard**.

*But anyway, I agree with the proposal of Remus Rusanu*

Comment: how can i install the lib_mysqludf_sys utility ??

Comment: Take a look into "installation" section here: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/blob/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.html ... but in general read the mysql udf manual

Comment: getting this error -----CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 0 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)

Comment: do you have a 32bit or 64bit operating system?

Comment: its 64 bit ubuntu 0.12...

Comment: Try recompiling for 64bit... modify your Makefile `gcc -m64 -fPIC -Wall ....` and `sudo make`

Comment: can you please elaborate more ..i went through this over some sites but cannot figure out how should i proceed..

Comment: About recompiling the mysqludf_sys for 64bit you can look at the answer on your post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-to-resolve-elfclass32-error-in-mysql-for-udf-lib-mysqludf-sys-so

Comment: no solution has been provided on this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-to-resolve-elfclass32-error-in-mysql-for-udf-lib-mysqludf-sys-so

Comment: Ok, try this: `gcc -m64 -fPIC -Wall -I/path/to/your/mysql/basedir -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o /path/to/save/your/new/lib_mysqludf_sys.so`

Comment: i will reply in a day or two...

Comment: @user21546 any news? :)

Comment: not yet !! im out for some days..i need to review it again on this project !!

Comment: hi ..m here now..can you please help me here...i dnt know how to install lib_mysqludf_sys...once it done...i will go further

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is fairly old and sorry for picking it up but I recently had the same requirement, so I created a MySQL UDF that uses JNI to call Java code from within a MySQL trigger. I'm posting this as a reference for similar future requests. I've checked in the code in bitbucket. You can download it from here: 
 [MySQLUDFJavaLauncher](https://bitbucket.org/dejard/dejard.bitbucket.org/src) and here is also a link to the [Instructions](http://dejard.bitbucket.org/). 
 Maybe this will help others.